# Page number top left on all pages

Tags: page-numbering

I want to put the page number on the left corner of the pages. I've already achieved it using fancyhdr:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\lfoot{\thepage}
```

The problem is that the first page remains with the page number on center. Can anyone solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you issuing `\maketitle` on the first page, perhaps? Also, what `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I was finally having problems with \maketitle, had to put:

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\lfoot{\thepage}

before the title, finally worked

Comment: The title says “top left”, but you use `\lfoot`. Do you mean “bottom left”, instead?

Answer (score 1):

Please always provide a minimal example which can be used to reproduce the issue. You can always edit your question to include further information. Code pasted in comments is essentially unreadable by human beings.

The reason the problem doesn't show up in a minimal completion of your fragment is the lack of any document element which triggers the `plain` page style. In `article` this is activated by `\maketitle`. In other classes it may be triggered by other commands such as `\chapter`.

To change the page number on `plain` pages, just read the `fancyhdr` documentation and redefine the `plain` style with the commands it provides.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\lfoot{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhf[lf]{\thepage}%
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\author{me}
\title{this}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: bottom left numbering on <code>plain</code> plage]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a running minimal example. Creating it might have already revealed the problem: I cannot reproduce your problem as my code (see below) does not show the behavior that you described.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\lfoot{\thepage}

test for first page \clearpage
test for second page

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first page of the OP might have the `title` block and hence a plain page style, or it is the starting page of a chapter (plain page style). Or there is something completely different going on. We cannot know yet.

Comment: Since I'm really noob at this and I don't know what exactly should I provide here is the code that correspond to the beginning of the document:

Comment: \documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.95cm,bmargin=2.95cm,lmargin=2.95cm,rmargin=2.95cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

Comment: \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Javier David Martín Romera}}

\makeatletter

Comment: \DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
  \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}

Comment: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\lfoot{\thepage}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
bla bla bla 
\end{document}

Comment: @JavierDavidMartínRomera Please add that code as one block to the question. The edit button is on the left bottom. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `article` that by default states `\pagestyle{plain}` everywhere, you can just redefine the `plain` page style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{plain} % so LaTeX updates the definition

\author{me}
\title{this}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Add the rest of your setup to this simple template. What you show in the comments scattered among the question and other answers shows nothing that can conflict with this.